# PyQt5 Поток и БД

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, sqlite, qthread

В главном потоке создается БД (SQLite) на `peewee`.
После чего создаются дополнительные потоки `QThread`.

Дополнительные потоки собирают информацию и через сигнал передают ее главному потоку.

В главном потоке пробовал `QueuedConnection` и `BlockingQueuedConnection` для обработки сигналов.  
Но все равно случается что 2-3 дополнительных потока одновременно вызывают один сигнал.
В результате чего БД встает и работа останавливается.

Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Жаль что вы не публикуете минимальный пример для демонстрации проблемы.

Вот небольшая имитация вами сказанного. БД заменил на QListWidget.
Пробуйте.

```
import sys
import threading
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


def thread(my_func):
    """  Запускает функцию в отдельном потоке """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        my_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        my_thread.start()
    return wrapper

@thread
def processing(signal):
    """ Эмулирует обработку каких-то данных """
    res = [i for i in 'hello']
    QThread.msleep(10)
    signal.emit(res)     # Посылаем сигнал в котором передаём полученные данные


class MyWidget(QWidget):

    my_signal = pyqtSignal(list, name='my_signal')

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.n_n = 1

        self.button     = QPushButton("Emit your signal!", self)
        self.listWidget = QListWidget(self)
        labels = ("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3")
        self.listWidget.addItems(labels)

        self.mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)        
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)

        # При нажатии на кнопку запускаем обработку данных
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: processing(self.my_signal))

        # Обработчик сигнала
        self.my_signal.connect(self.mySignalHandler, Qt.QueuedConnection)

    def mySignalHandler(self, data):  # Вызывается для обработки сигнала
        #print(data)
        item = QListWidgetItem()
        itemNumber = 0                # добавляем в верхнюю строку
        item.setText("{} {}".format(self.n_n, "".join(data)))
        self.listWidget.insertItem(itemNumber, item)
        self.n_n += 1


    def testProcessing(self):         
        """ для автоматического тестирования после запуска приложения """
        for i in range(1, 6):
            processing(self.my_signal)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MyWidget()
    window.show()

    # Два тестовых прогона: первый сразу, второй через 2 секунды.
    window.testProcessing()
    QTimer.singleShot(2000, window.testProcessing)

    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Только я использую QThread

Comment: @GoldenEagle  публикуете минимальный пример для демонстрации проблемы.